# Is there any panning facility working with zoom for highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for panning that work with zoom for highcharts.

Answer (score 7):

There is an example in the Highcharts API:

[Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.panning)

[Example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/pankey/)

The code you have to add is:

```
chart: {
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift'
    }
```